# Pandas: Delete rows of each group by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good afternoon, I have a dataframe like this where I have different groups that are reflected in the column "NumeroPosesion".

```
             Event  NumeroPosesion
0   completedPass               1
1   completedPass               1
2   takeon                      1
3   failedPass                  1
4   takeon                      1
5   dribbleYES                  1
6   shot                        1
7   takeon                      2
8   dribbleNO                   2
9   completedPass               2
10  completedPass               2
11  shot                        2
12  completedPass               2
13  completedPass               2
14  completedPass               2
```

The idea is the following:

1. When the first "Event" = "shot" appears, delete all the rows below that group.
2. Iterate from the last row of the group (it will be the one with "Event" = "shot" and go up until "Event" is different from "takeon", "completedPass" or "dribbleYES".
3. When it is different, delete all rows above the different one in the group.

Dataframe expected:

```
            Event  NumeroPosesion
0  takeon                 1
1  dribbleYES             1
2  shot                   1
3  completedPass          2
4  completedPass          2
5  shot                   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use boolean indexing with help of [`groupby.cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html)/[`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummin.html):

```
# remove rows after "shot" for each group
m1 = df.loc[::-1, 'Event'].eq('shot').groupby(df['NumeroPosesion']).cummax()

# remove rows before the first non "takeon"/"completedPass"/"dribbleYES"
m2 = (df.loc[m1, 'Event'].isin(['shot', 'takeon', 'completedPass', 'dribbleYES'])[::-1]
        .groupby(df['NumeroPosesion']).cummin()
      )

# slice
out = df[m1&m2]
```

Output:

```
            Event  NumeroPosesion
4          takeon               1
5      dribbleYES               1
6            shot               1
9   completedPass               2
10  completedPass               2
11           shot               2
```

Intermediates:

```
            Event  NumeroPosesion     m1     m2
0   completedPass               1   True  False
1   completedPass               1   True  False
2          takeon               1   True  False
3      failedPass               1   True  False
4          takeon               1   True   True
5      dribbleYES               1   True   True
6            shot               1   True   True
7          takeon               2   True  False
8       dribbleNO               2   True  False
9   completedPass               2   True   True
10  completedPass               2   True   True
11           shot               2   True   True
12  completedPass               2  False    NaN
13  completedPass               2  False    NaN
14  completedPass               2  False    NaN
```

Comment: This solution is perfect for me, I didn't know how to approach it and this works. Thank you very much for the help!